# How to use std::find algorithm on a vector of boolean elements

Tags: c++

I'm getting this **`std::_Bit_const_iterator`** error when trying to find an element in a **`std::vector<bool>`** using **`std::find`**. Can somebody explain what is it that I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> bin_mat;
    bin_mat = { { true, false, false },
                { false, false, true },
                { true, false, false }
              };
      
    for(const auto& row : bin_mat) {
        const std::vector<bool>::iterator row_itr = std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), true);
        std::size_t column_index = std::distance(row_itr, row.begin());
        
        std::cout << column_index << std::endl;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting **`conversion from ‘std::_Bit_const_iterator’ to non-scalar type ‘const iterator {aka const std::_Bit_iterator}’ requested const std::vector<bool>::iterator row_itr = std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), true);`**

Comment: Unrelated, the call to `std::distance` is odd. I think you mean to swap the arguments.

Comment: @cigien I just want the column index in that particular row

Comment: Then you need to swap the arguments, you want the distance from `begin` to `row_itr` not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `row` is a `const std::vector<bool>`, the return value of `std::find` is of type `std::vector<bool>::const_iterator`, and is not convertible to `std::vector<bool>::iterator`.

Note that `const iterator` is not at all the same thing as `const_iterator` - the former means the iterator itself cannot change (e.g. can't be pointed to a different element); the latter means the element pointed to cannot be changed via this iterator.

Just make it `auto row_itr = std::find(...)` and let the compiler figure out the right type.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a `iterator` to a `const` vector. Use a `const_iterator` and the code is fine:

```
for(const auto& row : bin_mat) {
    std::vector<bool>::const_iterator row_itr = std::find(row.begin(), row.end(), true);
                      // ^^ ----------- !!!
    // ...
}
```

You can, but you do not have to make the `row_itr` itself constant, but you can only get a `const_iterator` from a `const` vector (it is `const auto& row`). You cannot modify the container element via a `const_iterator`, while a `cosnt iterator` cannot be assigned a different iterator after initialization. They are different types and you cannot turn a `const_iterator` to a `iterator`, that would break const-correctness. Thats basically what the error message is trying to say, leaked implementation details aside it says:

```
conversion from ‘const_iterator’ to ‘const iterator’ requested
```

This is similar to pointers to constant ( -> `const_iterator`) vs constant pointer ( -> `const iterator`).